# Why are my lwc variables not defined?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

My Lightning Web Component operates as expected, data from the apex class is passed into the js class, and renders correctly in the lightning data table. However, in the @wire function, none of my console.logs show up as anything but undefined or an empty array. Debugging in chrome is the same thing, even as i step through the code all the variables are undefined. constantData was just a tester variable, this.data isnt defined either

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire} from 'lwc';
import getActiveMaterials from 
'@salesforce/apex/pcMaterialsClass.getActiveMaterials';

const columns = [
removed these for space as they aren't pertinent to the question 
]

export default class PcMaterials extends LightningElement {
@track aidata = [];
@track columns = columns;

@wire(getActiveMaterials)
wiredpcMaterials({error, data}) {
    if(data) {
        this.aidata = data;

        let constantData = this.aidata;

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(constantData);

    } else if(error) {
    this.error = error;  
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Added based on comments**

You are actually getting data but if you are logging directly, it returns proxy object in which the data will not be accessible directly, so you need to log the stringified data.

```
@wire(getActiveMaterials)
wiredpcMaterials({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.aidata = data;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('DATA => ', data, JSON.stringify(data));
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

Here, although you see `Array(0)` in data, you will get the array of records in `JSON.stringify(data)`

---

**OLD ANSWER**

When the component is rendered 1st time, all the wired services are registered and returns the object `{data:undefined,error:undefined}`. This is the reason you will always see them (data or error) as undefined on load of page. However, the service will invoke again when it returns the value (apex method return) to `data` if success or provide `error` value if failure.

Comment: that makes sense, any ideas on how to correctly console.log or see those variables when they do return values?

Comment: the conditions `if(data)....else if(error)....` is good. When either is returned, the logs inside the conditions will run

Comment: they show up in the log as undefined (or Array of 0) even within the if statement. Values do correctly show up in the component though